# Gradle caching on CI tool

Tags: gradle

I am trying to set up a project with cached gradle files. Our CI/CD tool is detecting changes on every build because gradle generates ever-changing files inside /.gradle/caches/. This means that the time saved on loading the cache is later spent on uploading the “new” cache (2 to 3 mins).

What I’m caching:

```
  paths:
    - ~/.gradle/caches
    - ~/.gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/configuration-cache # experimental feature
```

What I’m doing before caching:

```
      echo "deleting ever-changing files generated by gradle because they ruin the caching"
      rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/
      # seen in `gradle` docs:
      rm -f  ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
      rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
      # delete .lock files because they might contain timestamps
      find ~/.gradle/caches/ -name "*.lock" -type f -delete
      find .gradle/ -name "*.lock" -type f -delete
```

I’ve also noticed that inside `.gradle/caches/`there is `journal-1` folder which also contains a file with a timestamp:

```
➜  journal-1 cat file-access.properties
#Mon Oct 17 12:59:21 CEST 2022
inceptionTimestamp=1666004361205
```

I am feeling like I’m in a rabbit hole, there is not enough documentation about ever-changing files (like the ones that include a timestamp) or files that are not essential for the cache computation.

Could someone please help with this? I am using Gradle 7.5.1 *

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Gradle managed directories are [documented here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html). What CI/CD tool are you using, and how are you instructing it to fingerprint the caches? Can you try and tell it to only update the cache if any Gradle file `**/*.gradle*` changes?

Comment: @aSemy thanks for the link! the tree shown in the docs for the `gradle home` dir differs from my local + the `caches` inner dirs are not documented :/ and no, the CI simply takes paths to cache, it does not take any script.